# Rotating an image, and getting angle of rotation

Tags: android, image, animation, rotation

I have an round image in my app, and i want to let user rotate it by touching and sliding it up/down, and also i need to get the angle of this rotation( so if you touch the left bottom corner of the image, and later move your finger up to the top right corner, it will rotate by propper angle, and this angle should be accesable for real-time proccesing). What are the classes i should use or learn about?

Comment: Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287737/rotating-an-image-and-displaying-angle-of-rotation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend `ImageView` (actually, you could use any of a number of classes, but `ImageView` is a good start) and override `onDraw()`.  Capture touch events with an `OnTouchListener`.  There are loads of tutorials on the web, you could start [here](http://www.mysecretroom.com/www/programming-and-software/android-multi-touch-handling).  This class manipulates the bitmap using the `Matrix` class and only implements pan and zoom but rotation is easy with a matrix also.  To answer the question of how would you know the angle, you know because you set it!

In summary, learn how to extend `ImageView`, implement an `OnTouchListener` and utilize the `Matrix` class.