# Rotating an image, and displaying angle of rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-imageview, angle

I am making a virtual speedometer in android.
I use the RotateAnimation() to rotate the speedometer needle.

Is there any way to get the angular position of the needle during the rotation? That is, if the needle is rotating from 0 to 360 degree, I want to display the needles angle at each point during the period of animation. 
I use the following code to perform the animation.

```
RotateAnimation rpmNeedleDeflection = new RotateAnimation(-32, 213, (float) 135, needle.getHeight()/2);
rpmNeedleDeflection.setDuration(1500);
rpmNeedleDeflection.setFillAfter(true);
needle.startAnimation(rpmNeedleDeflection);
needle.refreshDrawableState();
```

Any help please...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may try to override applyTransformation

```
    RotateAnimation rpmNeedleDeflection = new RotateAnimation(fromDegrees, toDegrees, ...){
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,Transformation t) {
                    float currentDegree = fromDegrees+(toDegrees-fromDegrees)*interpolatedTime;
                    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
                };

            }
```

Comment: This code is not working. The needle is not deflecting at all.

Comment: sorry, i missed one line,  super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

Comment: Thanks buddy, it work like a charm. But, the needle is coming back to its original position once the animation is completed. I want it to stay there. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I think yes, first set the target rotation to the needle, needle.setRotation(213) before needle.startAnimation(rpmNeedleDeflection); and try

Comment: I'm getting an error while using setRotation(), "The method setRotation(int) is undefined for the type ImageView". Should I import something?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float) add from API level 11, i am wondering which API level you use?

Comment: then you may use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html

Comment: I've found another way solve my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rIHaN JiTHiN, could u plz share the code, even I have to rotate the needle according to my speed value. see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753730/rotating-speedometer-needle-gauge-around-its-center-as-the-speed-changes

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to keep the needle in final position:

```
if(currentDegree==toDegrees)
        {
            needle.refreshDrawableState();
            RotateAnimation nrpmNeedleDeflection=new rotateAnimation(toDegrees,toDegrees...);
            nrpmNeedleDeflection.setDuration(1); 
            nrpmNeedleDeflection.setFillAfter(true);
            needle.startAnimation(nrpmNeedleDeflection);
         }
```