# How can i calculate the degrees of an image after it stopped moving(android)?

Tags: android, motionevent

I am quite new to Android programming. What I need to do is calculate the degrees of an arrow after it has stopped moving. I am using the following code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            //double xValue, yValue;
            xValue = event.getX();
            yValue = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // reset the touched quadrants
                    for (int i = 0; i < quadrantTouched.length; i++) {
                        quadrantTouched[i] = false;
                    }

                    allowRotating = false;

                    startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    rotateDialer((float) (startAngle - currentAngle));
                    startAngle = currentAngle;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    allowRotating = true;
                    break;

            }
```

Need to be able to use `xValue` and `yValue`

```
private double getAngle(double xTouch, double yTouch) {
        double x = xTouch - (dialerWidth / 2d);
        double y = dialerHeight - yTouch - (dialerHeight / 2d);

        switch (getQuadrant(x, y)) {
            case 1:
                return Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;

            case 2:
            case 3:
                return 180 - (Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI);

            case 4:
                return 360 + Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;

            default:
                // ignore, does not happen
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

Insert `xValue` and `yValue` into `getAngle()`

```
public void run() {
            //double angleValue;
            setCheck(velocity);
            if (Math.abs(velocity) > 5 && allowRotating) {

                rotateDialer(velocity / 75);
                velocity /= 1.0666F;
                // post this instance again
                dialer.post(this);
            }else{

                /*Thread myThread = new Thread(new UpdateThread());
                myThread.start();*/
            }
        }
```

And call `getAngle()` from else inside the `run()` method. The problem is that the `xValue` and `yValue` only get calculated during motion events. The image keeps on spinning after the motion event is over. So I need to get the newest values from the `MotionEvent` when the image velocity reaches 0. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287737/rotating-an-image-and-displaying-angle-of-rotation

Comment: So you need the values when velocity is 0 and you don't know when the velocity is 0,is this what your are asking?

Comment: rIHaN JiTHiN, I think we had the same problem, I will try it out and let you know, thank you. Abhilash, I know when the velocity is 0, I just need to access the motion events while there is no motion

Comment: I just checked and I need to calculate the degrees when the arrow has stopped moving. The arrow stops at a position that is not pre defined. I need to get two variables from the onTouch method to calculate the angle. Thanx anyways