# android rotate animation get current angle / degrees when interrupted

Tags: android, animation, rotation, angle, degrees

i wonder how to get current angle / degrees in rotate animation when animation ends or gets interrupted?

my idea is when the animation gets interrupted when some button is clicked, the rotation will go counter-clockwise (current flow is clockwise), start from last angle /degree right when it gets interrupted.

i've tried using applyTransformation, but it seems not called :(

thanks!

Comment: `applyTransformation` is called for any animation that extends `android.view.animation.Animation`

Comment: i'll keep in mind @pskink thanks!

Comment: Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287737/rotating-an-image-and-displaying-angle-of-rotation).

Answer (score 5):

For this you must have to rotate your object not with simple rotate animation.
But Need to rotate with ObjectAnimator.

Here is simple example to find rotation angle of ball(imageview) .

```
ImageView  ball;

int i = ball.getMeasuredHeight();

ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball, "rotation", 0, 360);
animation.setDuration(10000);
ball.setPivotX(0);
ball.setPivotY(i / 2);
animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animation.start();
```

To get current rotation angle use:

```
ball.getRotation();
```